# Powerpoint vba slide background transparency

Tags: vba, powerpoint

If, in the PowerPoint GUI, I insert a picture as a slide background for a particular slide, I can vary the transparency of the image, so that other images and text placed on that slide stand out more - the background becomes just that, a more 'washed out' version of the original image.
Is there a way to do this programmatically using PowerPoint VBA?

I have done much internet searching and tried a variety of 'Transparency' type settings, all to no avail, they either bring up an error in the coding or fail to have the desired effect.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: There is no great documentation for Powerpoint VBA for some reason but many people export charts from Excel to Powerpoint as monthly reports for example so there are more examples of Excel VBA controlling Powerpoint out there so it might be worth looking for them.

Comment: Welcome Les! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Comment: Here is Microsoft's documentation for PowerPoint VBA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/powerpoint

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to post the code as I have tried and discarded suggestions, usually after also trying my own amendments to such code.